# Painting in multiple classes

Tags: java, swing, class, paint, mouselistener

I am not very good with using multiple classes in java, as I've always found it easier to do all of my code in 1 class. Recently I've found the need to use a second class for a game I'm making and I'm running into an error.

Right now I'm just trying to spawn the enemy where and when the user clicks.

Main Class -

```
package joey.rts;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class RTSMain extends JFrame implements MouseListener{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7122370886923000314L;
    public static BufferedImage menu,enemy;
    public static boolean onmenu,oneenemy;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new RTSMain();
    }
    public RTSMain(){
        init();
    }
    public void init(){
        setSize(1700,1100);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("RTS");
        addMouseListener(this);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if(onmenu == true){
            g2.drawImage(menu,0,0,this);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Enemy enemy = new Enemy();
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        enemy.spawnEnemy(x, y);

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Enemy class -

```
   package joey.rts;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Enemy{
    /**
     * 
     */
    public static BufferedImage enemy;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7898827977636314494L;
    public static RTSMain rts;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            enemy = ImageIO.read(new File(javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory() + "\\enemy.png"));
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public static void spawnEnemy(int x, int y){
        Graphics g = rts.getGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage(enemy,x,y,null);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what was your question? Where was this error you spoke of?

Comment: But I do see an OO problem. Why is `Enemy` extending `RTSMain`? If anything, I think `RTSMain` should contain a collection of `Enemy` and just iterate over them when drawing them. And `spawnEnemy()` should just spawn an instance of an `Enemy`, add it to the `Enemy` collection and it will drawn next time through the draw loop (I'm assuming you're using a game loop). Just what I noticed, but what is the error you're encountering?

Comment: you major issue is missing the `super.paint(...)` as 1st. code line inside `public void paint(Graphics g){`, then current painting will be reseted

Comment: `mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {` must contains `repaint()`

Answer (score 1):

In your Main class update your mouseClicked function to be :

```
@Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        Enemy enemy = new Enemy();
        int x=e.getX(); // get mouse positionX
        int y=e.getY();//get mouse positionY
        enemy.spawnEnemy(x,y);//spawn Enemy
    }
```

Consider saving the enemy objects if you need to reuse it later.
Also I see no need to extend anything in Enemy Class.

I've Updated Your Main and your Enemy class :

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Main extends JFrame implements MouseListener{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7122370886923000314L;
    public static BufferedImage menu,enemy;
    public static boolean onmenu,oneenemy;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Main().setVisible(true);
    }
    public Main(){
        init();
    }
    public void init(){
        setSize(1700,1100);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("RTS");
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if(onmenu == true){
            g2.drawImage(menu,0,0,this);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Enemy enemy = new Enemy();
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        enemy.spawnEnemy(x, y,this.getGraphics());

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

And this is the Enemy class :

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Enemy{

    public static BufferedImage enemy;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7898827977636314494L;
    public Enemy(){
        try {
            //MAKE SURE THAT THIS IS THE CORRECT IMAGE PATH
        enemy = ImageIO.read(new File(javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory() + "\\enemy.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Enemy.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    public void spawnEnemy(int x, int y,Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage(enemy,x,y,null);
    }
}
```

I've removed the instance variable of Main that was on Enemy class.

I've removed the static modifier for the spawnEnemy function.

I've sent the graphics object as an attribute to spawnEnemy function .

I've Moved the code that was in main method in Enemy class to the Enemy Constructor.

Hope it helps !

Comment: It depends on the behavior needed in the game , he asked for the user clicks action anyway :)

Comment: I did that and it just constantly opened new JFrames. So I removed the extended RTSMain in the Enemy class, and moved the buffered image to the enemy class. Same error still. ( Updating above code one sec )

Comment: Are you calling your `Enemy`'s `main()` class? If not, it's never reading in the image for the enemy. I don't think your `Enemy` class needs a `main`, though, unless it's for a unit test. Change it to the constructor or an `init()` method. Just make sure it gets called for each enemy, however. I'd re-architect this game, but that should get you working.

Comment: Ahmed Amr, I'm getting the same error that I was getting before.

Comment: I've tried it at my machine and it's working , probably you are getting the error because of the enemy.png path are not correct. try to put the direct path to the image in the code and check again. If it didn't solve the problem paste the error here.

Answer (score 0):

It just seemed easier to paste an answer than to try to explain it in a comment. Your OO is a bit off. Add this to your `RTSMain` class:

```
protected ArrayList<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
protected BufferedImage enemyImage = null;
...
public void init() {
    ...
    // everything you already have...
    enemyImage = //read in your enemy image here
    ...
}
...

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // this takes place of Enemy.spawn(), get rid of it
    int x = e.getX(); // get mouse positionX
    int y = e.getY(); //get mouse positionY
    Enemy enemy = new Enemy( enemyImage, x, y );
    Enemies.add( enemy );
    // Iterate over list above to draw each enemy in your paintComponent method
}
```

Also, JFrame doesn't have a `paintComponent()` method, which you need to override to do your painting (`paint()` is deprecated). Add a `JPanel`, override it's `paintComponent()` and so on. For a game, you'll probably want to create a game loop to do your painting, unless it's very turn-based.

Happy coding.